# Confused when trying to calculate the derivative of $y(x)$

Tags: derivatives

I have been given an exercise to compute the derivative of the following function:

$$y(x) = e^{-(y(x)+2)^2} \arctan(y(x)) $$

Now, what confuses me is that I don't know what's the variable by which we derive? Is this another way of writing:

$$y = e^{-(y+2)^2} \arctan(y), $$ or do I need to derive $y$ by $x$ somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this some sort of implicit function? When you write, for example, $\text{arctan}~{y}$, is that $y$ the same $y$ as on the left-hand side of the expression?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, this is all I have been given. I suspect it _may_ be an implicit function, and even if it is it's given in a strange way.

Comment: It's a trick question. What the most appropriate way of attacking it is depends on the context in which this exercise was given.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but wolfram alpha says the only solution satisfying this given expression in Real set is $y=0$.

Comment: More likely than not it is a trick question. The exercise states only the following:

Compute the derivative of the following functions: 

After which follows a series of functions ranging from simple functions, parametric derivatives, logarithmic derivatives, and this one. That's why I suspect it _might_ be an implicit function but it doesn't seem like one.

Answer (score 1):

The way it is written - it is an equation for $y$ which can be solved (in principle) to give you (one or more)  fixed numbers. Thus $y$ is (one or more)  constants and $y'=0$. If there was another term involving $x$ explicitly - perhaps you could have a non-zero derivatve.

Answer (score 0):

By the product and the chain rule we get
$$y'(x)=e^{-(y(x)+2)^2}(-2(y(x)+2))y'(x)\arctan(x))+e^{-(y(x)+2)^2}\frac{1}{1+y(x)^2}\times y'(x)$$ and solve this for $y'(x)$

Comment: Is this a derivative of an implicit function?

Comment: Yes this can we say.

Comment: This derivative can be solved for $$y'(x)$$